# Can you play Mortal Kombat local on two Switches?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online, mortal-kombat-11, mortal-kombat-1-2023

My friend has a copy of MK11 and MK1 for Switch. If I bought copies could I play against her with my own Switch (Lite)?